# Elasticsearch Dynamicly Index Choosing To Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I seperated myindex hourly such as myindex_YYYY-MM-DD-HH. I have my date field which is not created automatically. I created my own mapping so myindex does not contain timestamp etc. My wish is, when I run query on myindex if I passed daterange parameter gte: 15:00 to lt: 18:00, I want elasticsearch to run those query on myindex_2017-12-01-15,myindex_2017-12-01-16,myindex_2017-12-01-17 not include other indices. I know graylog can do that. Is there any way to do that?

By the way, I use elasticsearh 5.1 version

Comment: Can't you do it with a simple script Python or Shell with regex ?

Comment: I am using c#, NEST. I can do it in my code but I wonder is there any mechanism like graylog @tricky

Comment: Graylog is a layer on top of Elasticsearch, similar to Kibana, which performs the same optimization. ES itself cannot do that, but your client code can and should.

Comment: thank you for response @Val. I was expecting the answer. I wish there was a trick :)